# My app works when apk put directly onto phone but when taken from Google Play store it crashes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, google-play

Whenever I put my app apk directly onto the phone it works fine and does not crash but when I upload to Google Play and download from there, it opens then crashes on splashscreen, sometimes randomly in the app it will just crash.

No idea what could be causing this, the app works for other peoples android phones but on my HTC Desire 530 it keeps crashing.

Has anyone had any similar problems and would anyone have any idea of where I could even look to find this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.gemproduction" android:versionCode="46" android:versionName="1.14">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
<application android:label="Gem" android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:allowBackup="false">
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Log from google Play:

```
  #00  pc 000000000004d3a2  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm     /libsqlcipher.so (validate_license_key+33)

  #01  pc 000000000004d883  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so (sqlcipher_license_key_status+66)

  #02  pc 000000000005f48f  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so

  #03  pc 0000000000092bff  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so

  #04  pc 0000000000085459  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so

  #05  pc 000000000007fa93  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so

   #06  pc 000000000005abcb  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so

   #07  pc 000000000007ecdb  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so

   #08  pc 000000000005a2bb  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so

   #09  pc 000000000005a41b  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so

   #10  pc 000000000005a4d1  /data/app/com.gemproduction-1/lib/arm/libsqlcipher.so (sqlite3_prepare16_v2+16)

   #11  pc 00000000000006c0  <unknown>
```

I am not using ProGuard.

Error Log:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/miCqx.jpg

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: @MohammedAtif I added the error log that I was getting from Google Play for the crash

Comment: you need to provide error log from device.

Comment: @MohammedAtif how do I get that when I cannot debug as the problem is only occurring when downloaded from google play?

Comment: You must use crash reporting tools like Crashlytics

Comment: @MohammedAtif I figured out how to get error log from phone but it now seems to be working and isn't crashing? no idea what was causing it

Comment: @MohammedAtif got the error log from the phone now

Comment: @Ciaran is above log is from phone..?

Comment: from above log I assume there must be a issue with license key , are you sure that the licensing key is not  altered or encrypted before publishing in Google play console..?

Answer (score 1):

Does your app require permissions?

**If your answer is yes**, try adding them manually, but remember to request the permissions in your app.

Why does it happen? Or why is it necessary?

**When you install app via apk application, all permissions are granted**, otherwise, via Google Play, the same doesn't happen.